# is p3p response information accessible from javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, p3p

As I understand, the webserver will send p3p information to the browser, but will the browser then present that data to the javascript engine via some API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- P3P information is not exposed to JavaScript, and generally has very little effect on browser behavior in general, other than a few weird edge cases on MSIE.

Comment: Do you know a reference to these edge cases?

Comment: Check the "related questions" sidebar for some examples. The most common "gotcha" appears to be that P3P headers can be required if you set cookies from pages loaded in IFRAMEs.